# Flutter - Connect to Bluetooth Thermometer

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, sensors

My internship boss asked me to connect thermometer with flutter using Bluetooth, but I don't know how to do it. I searched through the net for examples. My boss has an app for students which can measure body temperature for the students. Can anyone give me any idea n how to do it? Or at least, please provide me the links where I will find an easy way to learn on how I may be able to do it? I have been scratching my head for 4 days. I saw some videos on ardiuno uno, but those are related to measuring humidity and surrounding temperature. My boss want me to measure body temperature. I do not even know where to start and where to end.
Any expert please provide me some materials where I can learn this easily.

Comment: how is thermal printer related to temperature of the body? how can i make the code measure body temperature?

Comment: I am not an expert but if you can give more information regarding which hardware (i.e. thermometer with bluetooth interface), someone might be able to help. Connecting to the thermometer via bluetooth should be the same as other bluetooth services. But you must know how to interpret the message (i.e. event) from sensor. For prototyping, you should use web or python where you can test easily rather than Flutter first. [Here](https://gist.github.com/mattdsteele/0fa9cafc4a95738181137547eae21fc8), somebody did similar task using web for BBQ thermometer. Good luck.

Comment: [Here](https://sifter.org/simon/journal/20200106.html) is an example in Python. He provided a link to hardware, i.e. CVS bluetooth thermometer but it is not working anymore. So I searched for alternatives and I found one with good reviews on [ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/353184352755?chn=ps&mkevt=1&mkcid=28). I think this example is *easier* for you to test.

Comment: Regarding your question in the comment, I don't think you have to code anything for the thermometer to start measuring. You just need power the thermometer on and then, it should send its measurements via bluetooth. You just need to connect it using Bluetooth and wait for the measurements to arrive and use as you wish. Consider it as a water tap. You just need to put a bucket (i.e. connecting via Bluetooth) to collect the measurements after opening the tap (i.e. powering on the thermometer).

Comment: There is not enough detail in the question to easily help. Try breaking it down into smaller questions. You need to know (or share) more information about the thermometer. Is it Bluetooth BLE or Classic (BR/EDR)? If it is BLE, do you have information about the GATT Services and Characteristics available on it? If not, use a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool such as [nRF connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to find out.This should be enough information to use [flutter_blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue)